# Module factory is not returning data

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to read JSON reply from server. You can find my code here.
https://github.com/ameyjah/feeder

In firefox firebug, I can see that server has returned JSON reply but when I store that into $scope.variable, I am not able to access that information.

Module code
var res

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('feedFetcher', ['$resource',
        function($resource) {
            var actions = {
                'sites': {method:'GET', params: { action:"sites"} ,isArray:false},                           
                'feeds': {method:'GET', params: { action:"sites"} ,isArray:false}
            }
            res = $resource('/api/:action', {}, actions);
            return res
        }
    ]);
```

Controller code

```
$scope.sites = feedFetcher.sites().sites;
console.log($scope.sites);
```

Reply seen in firebug:

```
{
  "sites": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "google"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "yahoo"
    }
  ]
}
```

I think I have messed up the way I should define my factory but I am not able to identify. Any help would be helpful.

Comment: The definition of boths sites and feeds is the same?

Comment: @JeffFoster oh that is just copy paste error but sites() still doesn't return data.

Answer (score 1):

When you call sites() it returns an empty object and initiates an AJAX request, which will populate the "sites" property on that object.  I think you should use it like this:

```
$scope.results = feedFetcher.sites();
console.log($scope.results.sites); // will be undefined as AJAX not complete
```

Then in your html you can use the results and they will be filled in when AJAX completes, or watch for it:

```
$scope.$watch('results.sites', function() {
    // this will be called twice, once initially
    // and again whenever it is changed, aka when AJAX completes
    console.log($scope.results.sites);
};
```